# Current user gets overwritten with ria service authentication

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, forms-authentication, authorization, ria

I have a SL 4 applicaiton with RIA service for authentication(Forms + IE9). Consider following scenario

- user A logs into the system,
- now user B does the same,
- user A performs some operation and it appears that inside `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User` are hidden credentials for user B which is a catastrophy

Here's part of my web.config
 `<authentication mode="Forms" >
                         <forms name="MY_COOKIE_NAME" timeout="180"/>
        </authentication>`

and code part responsible for login

```
public AuthenticationUser Login(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, string customData)
    { 
        var retUser = new DefaultUser();
        if (/*check credentials*/)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
            retUser = CreateAuthenticatedUserData(userName);

        }
        return retUser;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that problem lies in the internet browser - never open two instances of your application in two tabs of the same browser - session/cookies/whatever are shared